# Insert data from Google Sheets into Listview

Tags: java, android, google-sheets

I'm developing an Android app using Google Sheets as a database.

I have information about books in a Google Sheet  (title, author, cover, date, etc). I want to retrieve this information and show it in a "Listview" in the "Spreadsheets" Activity. I created a "BookItem" object and an "BookAdapter" adapter. In the "Spreadsheets.java" I have the read method, called "getDataFromApi()". I know that this method works, but I don't know how to adapt it to my "BookAdapter" and show the information on the ListView.

This is mi code:

```
public class BookItem {
static String title_item;
static Drawable cover_item; //probar con String

public BookItem(String title, Drawable cover){
    super();
    this.title_item = title;
    this.cover_item = cover;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title_item;
}

public void setTitle(String title){
    this.title_item = title;
}

public static Drawable getCover() {
    return cover_item;
}

public void setCover(Drawable cover) {
    this.cover_item = cover;}
```

This is my BookAdapter:

```
public class BookAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private ArrayList<BookItem> items;
List<BookItem> items;
private Context context;

public BookAdapter (Context context, List<BookItem> items) {
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public BookItem getItem(int position) {
    return this.items.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    public final ImageView cover_item;
    public final TextView title_item;

    public ViewHolder (ImageView cover_item, TextView title_item){
        this.cover_item = cover_item;
        this.title_item = title_item;
    }
}

@Override
public View getView (int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    ImageView cover_item;
    TextView title_item;

    if (view == null) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.fila_lista_miestanteria, viewGroup, false); //se mete aqui en getView por ser baseAdapter
        title_item = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.book_title_item);
        cover_item = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.book_cover_item);
        view.setTag(R.id.book_title_item, title_item);
        view.setTag(R.id.book_cover_item, cover_item);
    }
    else {
        cover_item = (ImageView) view.getTag(R.id.book_cover_item);
        title_item = (TextView)view.getTag(R.id.book_title_item);
    }
    BookItem bookItem = getItem(position);
    cover_item.setImageDrawable(bookItem.getCover());
    title_item.setText(bookItem.getTitle());

    return view;
}
```

}

```
public class Spreadsheets extends Activity {

static String book_title, book_author, book_date, book_category, book_description, book_rating, book_cover;
static String read_only = "no";
static String book_favorite = "no";
static GoogleAccountCredential mCredential;
private ListView bookList;
private TextView mOutputText;
ProgressDialog mProgress;
Context context;
List<String> rst;
List<BookItem> resultados;
BookAdapter adapter;

private static final String[] SCOPES = {SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.spread);

    // mOutputText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputText);
   bookList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.bookList);
    //  mOutputText.setText("");

    mProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mProgress.setMessage("Calling Google Sheets...");

    // Initialize credentials and service object.
    mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
            getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
            .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());

    System.out.print("read only es igual a "+ read_only);
    new MakeRequestTask(mCredential).execute();
}

public void rellenar(){
    System.out.println("VOY A HACER NEW BOOK ADAPTER ");
    adapter = new BookAdapter(context, resultados);
    bookList.setAdapter(adapter);
    System.out.println("SETADAPTER");
}

private class MakeRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {
    private Exception mLastError = null;
    MakeRequestTask(GoogleAccountCredential credential) {
    }

    @Override
    protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            if(read_only.equals("no")) {
                setDataToApi();
                return null;
            }
            else {
                return getDataFromApi();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mLastError = e;
            cancel(true);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private List<String> getDataFromApi() throws IOException {

        String range = "Sheet1!A1:H";
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        ValueRange response = CreateSpreadsheets.mService.spreadsheets().values()
                .get(CreateSpreadsheets.spreadsheet_id, range)
                .execute();
        List<List<Object>> values = response.getValues();
        if (values != null) {
            for (List row : values) {
                results.add(row.get(0) + ", " + row.get(7));
            }
        }
        //funcion();
        return results;
    }

    private void setDataToApi() throws IOException {

        String range = "Sheet1!A2:H";
        List<List<Object>> values = new ArrayList<>();

        List<Object> data1 = new ArrayList<>();

        data1.add(book_title);
        data1.add(book_author);
        data1.add(book_date);
        data1.add(book_category);
        data1.add(book_description);
        data1.add(book_rating);
        data1.add(book_cover);
        data1.add("a");

        values.add(data1);
        ValueRange valueRange = new ValueRange();
        valueRange.setMajorDimension("ROWS");
        valueRange.setRange(range);
        valueRange.setValues(values);

        ValueRange body = new ValueRange().setValues(values);

        AppendValuesResponse response =
                CreateSpreadsheets.mService.spreadsheets().values().append(CreateSpreadsheets.spreadsheet_id, range, body)
                        .setValueInputOption("RAW")
                        .execute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //mOutputText.setText("");
        mProgress.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> output) {
        mProgress.hide();
        if (output == null || output.size() == 0) {
            //   mOutputText.setText("No results returned.");
        } else {
            if(read_only.equals("no")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Spreadsheets.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                //  mOutputText.setText("Se ha aÃ±adido un libro a su lista");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("VOY A RELLENAR LA LISTA");
                rellenar();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {

    }

}
```

}

The "spread.xml" is a list, and the "fila_list_miestanteria.xml" is a TextView&ImageView to show the book info.

Thank you so much!